# Is there electricity in this wall?

Tags: shelving

I am trying to put up some shelves so am using a Bosch Truvo detector to find hazards in the wall. It appears to be giving inconsistent readings. I have recalibrated the unit according to the manual.

I have recorded a demonstration to show my problem.

https://youtu.be/Tg5TxNcVnLs

Is this user error or is the unit faulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions<sup>1</sup> state that,

> - **Make sure that you are properly earthed when taking measurements.** 
>   If
>   you are not properly earthed (e.g. by wearing insulating footwear or
>   by standing on a ladder), it will not be possible to locate live
>   cables.
> - **Hold the measuring tool by the intended gripping surface (1) only, so
>   as not to influence the measurement.**
> - **Do not attach any stickers or labels to the sensor area on the rear of the measuring tool.**
>   Metal
>   labels in particular will affect measuring results.
> - **Do not wear gloves when taking measurements and make sure that you are
>   properly earthed.**
>   If you are not properly earthed, the identification
>   of live wires may be impaired.
> - **When taking measurements, avoid devices
>   that emit strong electric, magnetic or electromagnetic fields.**
>   If
>   possible, deactivate all tools whose radiation could interfere with
>   the measurement and switch off the corresponding functions or tools.

While this is arguably not what one might expect from such a device, the manufacturer have done what is required of them to make the requirements of this device clear. Earthing is likely the most important factor, so try mitigating this with an Earth Bonding Strap and Plug.

---

1. Robert Bosch Power Tools GmbH (2021). Truvo. [online] bosch-diy.com, pp.16, 20. Available at: https://www.bosch-diy.com/storage/en-gb/truvo-100039682-original-pdf-364483-en-gb.pdf [Accessed 12 Apr. 2022].

‌

Comment: Grounding (earthing) yourself is so important, they say it _twice_! Funny, thought, that they specify "standing on a ladder". I own several aluminum/aluminium ladders, I wonder if one of those count. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a multidetector.

I have one and it will pick up electric cables as well as nails and screws in the wall.

Used it last week when putting a shelf in my daughter's room and it found a screw in the plasterboard right where I wanted to put a shelf screw. Meant I had to move the shelf screws a bit but avoided an issue.

Comment: Think the OP's problem is that holding it one way, it shows something there, but holding it another way, it shows nothing there.

Comment: @crip659 so address the OP… I know how to hold mine. Have you got one? And how did your testing go?

Comment: I do not have one, just watched the video that the OP linked to.  The video did show two different results depending on how it was held at the same spot.  OP is concerned about driving a screw into a wire.

Comment: @SolarMike I know what it is and how it is supposed to work. As crip659 says, I am indeed asking if it is faulty or if the fault lies with the user (me).

Comment: You find studs and live wires by scanning side to side, electrical cables are required to be attached to the stud 1-1/4” away from the face. The field produced by a energized cable may be detected several inches away try scanning right to left, some of these us ultrasonic signals to find the stud pushing hard can confuse the electronics again sweep side to side and you will have more consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical cables *should* be running vertically, not horizontally, at places where one may want to drill through (in UK at least). Try moving the detector up and down, and side to side, to ascertain which way the cable (if that's what is being detected) goes.

Comment: In the US, electric cables are commonly strung across a wall horizontally, especially when wiring several outlets along a wall. We don't run the cable from one outlet, down through the floor (or up to the attic) and back up _unless_ it's a retrofit and there's access from above or below. In new construction it's cheaper to spend time drilling holes and running the wiring horizontally, than it is to spend copper running the wiring up and down. The OP is, however, in the UK according to his profile.

Comment: @FreeMan Correct, I am in England

Answer (score -1):

Good video accompanying your question and this answer is based on both the question and the video.

You need to carefully read the user manual.  It appears from the video that you either have not, or are ignoring significant parts of it.

Specifically, pages 20 and 21 tell you exactly how to hold the device and what to expect if you do not, or if you (for example) hold it with a stick.  Page 22 further describes techniques for detecting live cables: detection improved by cables in use, by moisture in walls, by what you wear on your hands and feet, and by the positioning of your hands and feet.    Page 23 explains how to recalibrate the instrument if your readings seem suspicious and pages 24 and 25 explain how to diagnose problems such as yours.

The instructions are, as far as instruction manuals go, *freakishly* thorough, clear, unambiguous, and helpful.   I'm certain that if you read and follow all the instructions carefully you'll be successful.

[image]

Comment: A better answer would quote and cite the appropriate sources

Comment: I cited the source: the user manual.  I do not agree that answers need to include links or quotes from manuals, especially not vanillla manuals like "the user manual", and especially not when entire sections of the manual are relevant.   I think, in fact, *Questions* should include links to manuals and the sections that have been exhausted before coming here to ask for more.    There are almost three entire pages of the manual explaining what OP is doing wrong.  You want me to quote them???

Comment: Yes, providing a full citation is needed in StackExchange https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284971/371745

Comment: #beNice - few people read manuals, especially for a tool that has a very simple UI. His reaction is pretty understandable as it looks like a strange result he gets. I checked the manual and it does have 1 paragraph explaining that good grounding is necessary: "Always ensure that you hold the measuring tool firmly without
gloves to enable a good grounding. Also ensure that ladders/scaffolding
must be grounded. Avoid ladders/scaffolding whose supports have plas-
tic caps underneath them. Do not wear insulating footwear."

Comment: Hey sorry --- I did not realize that the person asking for the quote was the OP.   Yes my comment is not nice as part of an answer.  Apologies.  I thought some third party was scolding me!      However I do not interpret your meta citation as requiring that a question about how to use a device demands that Answers cite the device's own user manual.  And I'm not going to look on meta.diy for a contrary citation but I'm pretty sure the spirit of one of the guidelines is to do some basic research before you ask a question and refer to it in the question.   But I'll add specific references anyway.

Comment: And [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) FWIW is my contra meta.

Comment: @jay613 a close vote is a more appropriate way to signal to someone that maybe they should take a look in the instructions rather than a somewhat hostile non-answer (as it was originally, it's toned down a bit now). Thank you for helping people as much as you do, but a little bit of politeness in today's broken world goes a long way.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Hear, hear. We all need to remember that there are people on the other end of our keyboards.